# How do you determine if a variable is a slice or array?

Tags: go

I have a function that is passed a map, each element of which needs to be handled differently depending on whether it is a primitive or a slice.  The type of the slice is not known ahead of time.  How can I determine which elements are slices (or arrays) and which are not?

Comment: When you say "being handled differently," what do you mean exactly?

Comment: if value_is_slice { do_something() } else { do_something_else() }

Comment: Go is not capable of ad-hoc polymorphism?  Seems to me like you can use the implicit interfaces in Go to get different behavior depending on whether you're passing a slice or an array.  See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/N4MBApd09M8

Comment: What is different about `do_something()` and `do_something_else()`?  How does the behavior vary?

Comment: It is not possible to add interfaces for every possible type.  (Someone might just pass in a new `type { a, b, c int }` )  I just want to figure out if the type of each element is a slice type or not.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Have a look at the [`reflect`](http://godoc.org/reflect) package.
[Here is a working sample](http://play.golang.org/p/VhIrvgEytL) for you to play with.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    m["a"] = []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    m["b"] = [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4}

    test(m)
}

func test(m map[string]interface{}) {
    for k, v := range m {
        rt := reflect.TypeOf(v)
        switch rt.Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice:
            fmt.Println(k, "is a slice with element type", rt.Elem())
        case reflect.Array:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array with element type", rt.Elem())
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is something else entirely")
        }
    }
}
```